# Using reactive to resubscribe each time another event occurs

Tags: c#-4.0, system.reactive

I want to subscribe to an observable, but only run an action once until a different IObservable fires. Each time the other IObservable fires, I'd like to be resubscribed and run my action once. The following code should accomplish that:

```
Action<object> act = null;
act = _ => {
    DoThis();
    obj.Observable1.SkipUntil(obj.CompletedObservable).Take(1).Subscribe(act);
};
obj.Observable1.Take(1).Subscribe(act);
```

Is there a more proper way to do this with the Rx framework? If not, how could I wrap this pattern into an extension?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I've got it:

```
obj
    .CompletedObservable
    .StartWith(/* value of suitable type for CompletedObservable */)
    .Select(x => obj.Observable1.Take(1))
    .Switch()
    .Subscribe(x => DoThis());
```

Comment: StartWith made this a perfect solution. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you want something like this:

```
first  -----1------------2-------------3--4--------->
            |            |             |  |
second ---------A--B----------C-D-E-----------F---G->
                |             |               |
final  ---------A-------------C---------------F----- >
```

For this, a combination of `SelectMany`, `Take`, and `TakeUntil` should work.  I would say:

```
var final = from f in first
            from s in second.Take(1).TakeUntil(first)
            select s;
```

The `.Take(1)` ensures that you only get the first item after the first (for 1, 2, and 4).  The `.TakeUntil(first)` covers 3, so that F only gets passed once (to 4).  If you have a nice name for this operation, it would be easy to wrap into a method taking the two observables as parameters.

Comment: Good solution. The diagram is something I should have included.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the following:

```
obj.CompletedObservable
    .Select(_ => obj.Observable1.Next().First())
    .Subscribe(_ => DoThis());
```

Comment: Note that you didn't seem to use any elements from either observable - in that case perhaps a .Zip ping both collection would do it, unless Observable1 rarely fires and you want to wait for the next one.

Comment: Unfortunately, Observable1 must be handled before CompletedObservable fires.